# Assign consecutive trial numbers to data frame beginning at match

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, row-number

I want to assign consecutive trial numbers (1-16) to a long dataframe depending on certain values of other variables.

It should look like this (simplified):

```
value   trial_no
videoA      1
other       1
videoB      2
other       2
other       2
videoC      3
...
```

This basically does what I want, but it just assigns the row numbers.

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(trial_no = case_when(grepl('video', value) ~ row_number())) %>%
  fill(trial_no)
```

This might do what I want, but yet it assigns 16 to all.

```
for (vid in c(1:16)) {
  df2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(trial_no = case_when(grepl("video", value) ~ vid)) %>%
    fill(trial_no) 
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is an easy solution to this.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please include data in your question next time, as I did in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: sure, will do! sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grepl` and count the `TRUE`s

```
transform(dat, trial_no=cumsum(grepl('video', value)))
#    value trial_no
# 1 videoA        1
# 2  other        1
# 3 videoB        2
# 4  other        2
# 5  other        2
# 6 videoC        3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(value = c("videoA", "other", "videoB", "other", 
"other", "videoC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @groovyturtle Cool, happy to help! Please consider to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on Stack Overflow, cheers!